# Speeding up my Python code for reading from Excel, performing geospatial analysis and writing to Excel files

Tags: python, performance, excel

I have written a Python snippet that reads lat and long stored in an Excel file. Converts them to a point which is then used to perform multiple geospatial analysis including buffer, intersection, and searching within a shapefile's attribute table (finding count of a specific attribute occurrence and a single row can have multiple attributes in the same column). This code snippet is very slow. I need to traverse around 2000 records and search for around 179 attributes (count) against 10 different radii. It takes around 2.45 minutes to traverse against 1 point for 10 radii and search for the count of only 10 attribute occurrences. Is there any way to speed up this process?

I am attaching the code below.

```
# importing libraries
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

#loading input excel
book = load_workbook(r'File path of input file.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
bookOut = r'outputfile.csv'
#outputSheet = bookOut.active
#searching for a specific category and returning its count
def bSearch(lst, cat):
     c = 0
     for index, row in lst[0:len(lst)].iterrows():
        if cat in row['Category_t']:
            c = c+1
     return (c)
        
# creates buffer
def createbuf(p,r):
    bufp = p['geometry'].buffer(distance = r)
    buf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = bufp, crs = ucs.crs)
    return (buf)

# calculates intersection
def calint(b,u):
    areaoi = gpd.overlay(u, b, how= "intersection") 
    return (areaoi)

# shapefiles Input
ucs = gpd.read_file(r'Boundary.shp')
ucs = ucs.to_crs(epsg=32643)

#Business List
business = gpd.read_file(r'List of Categories.shp')
business = business.to_crs(epsg=32643)
businessArray = [
'Cat1','Cat2','Cat3','Cat4','Cat5','Cat6','Cat7','Cat8','Cat9','Cat10'
]
radiusVals=[0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3.000, 4.000, 5.000, 7.000, 10.000]
# lat long
latlng = []
i = 0
otp = []
for row in range(143, sheet.max_row+1):
    detStore = []
    ind = 0
    for column in "AB":
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        latlng.append(sheet[cell_name].value)
        detStore.append(sheet[cell_name].value)
    for column in "CD":
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        detStore.append(sheet[cell_name].value)
    # PCS SRID
    p1 = Point((latlng[i],latlng[i+1]))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[latlng[i+1],latlng[i]]})
    po = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = [p1], crs = ucs.crs)
    po['geometry'] = po['geometry'].to_crs(epsg = 32643)
    print(i,  "--", latlng[i+1], latlng[i])
    i = i+2
    # calling functions
    for r in range (0, len(radiusVals)):
        outputStore = []
        for d in range (0, len(detStore)):
            outputStore.append(detStore[d])
        outputStore.append(radiusVals[r])
        bufo = createbuf(po,(radiusVals[r]/111))
        aoi = calint(bufo ,ucs)
        busList = calint(bufo, business)
        for b in range (0, len(businessArray)):
            buSearch = bSearch (busList,businessArray[b])
            outputStore.append(buSearch)
        otp.append(outputStore)
print (otp)
fields = ['Location X', 'Location Y', 'Type', 'Name', 'Radius', 'Cat1','Cat2','Cat3','Cat4','Cat5','Cat6','Cat7','Cat8','Cat9','Cat10']
with open(bookOut, 'w',  newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer (f)
    write.writerow(fields)
    write.writerows(otp)
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/393860/115.

Comment: Do you have an input `.shp` file we can use to test your code with? I'd like to see if there's anything I can do for you, even after all this time, but reviewing Python-Excel combos without having a dataset to test with is adding complexity. And possibly the reason your question hasn't been answered yet.